# redireccin¿onar a otra pagina

Tags: php

estoy haciendo un formulario en varias páginas dado que es muy grande, pero cuando lleno los datos personales los guardo en un base de datos y se guardan bien y en ese mismo botón quiero direccionar a la siguiente página, pero cual oprimo el botón me muestra lo de la página en otra ventana
el codigo que uso en el php que redirecciono y guardo es el siguiente:

```
 $paciente= "INSERT INTO pacientes (Id_paciente, nombre_paciente, apellido_paterno_paciente, apellido_materno_paciente, correo, expediente, 
                                religion, telefono, celular, fecha_consulta,
                                unidad, dx, qx, sexo, ayuno, horas_ayuno)
    VALUES ( 'NULL', '$db[0]', '$db[1]', '$db[2]', '$db[3]', '$db[4]',
    '$db[5]', '$db[6]', '$db[7]', '$db[8]', '$db[9]', '$db[10]', '$db[11]', '$db[12]', '$db[13]', '$db[14]')";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $paciente)) {
    //echo "New record created successfully";
    //header("Location: insertar_clientes.php? variable1=$nombre_vendedor&variable2=$puesto&variable3=$correo&variable4=$tel");
    //print('Se almaceno la información correctamente.');
    mysqli_close($conn);
    //header("location:signos_vitales.php");
    $servername = "localhost";
    $database = "somnus";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password) ;
        mysqli_select_db($conn, $database) or die ("Error al conectar a la base de datos".mysql_error());
    $query = "SELECT  *  FROM pacientes WHERE Id_paciente in (select MAX(Id_paciente) from pacientes)";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    //mysqli_data_seek ($resultado, 2);
    $extraido= mysqli_fetch_array($resultado);
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['nombrePaciente']=$extraido['nombre_paciente'].' '.$extraido['apellido_paterno_paciente'].' '.$extraido['apellido_materno_paciente'];
    $_SESSION['idpaciente']=$extraido['Id_paciente'];
    //echo "<input type='text' name='almacen' id='almacen' value='5' readonly> <br/> <br/>";
    //echo $extraido['num_cot'];
    mysqli_close($conn);
   header("location: signos_vitales.php"); 
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
```

Answer (score 0):

Para usar `header()` es necesario que no se hayan enviado cabeceras.

De la página de PHP:

> Recuerde que header() debe ser llamado antes de mostrar nada por
> pantalla, etiquetas HTML, líneas en blanco desde un fichero o desde
> PHP. Es un error muy común leer código con funciones como include o
> require, u otro tipo de funciones de acceso de ficheros que incluyen
> espacios o líneas en blanco que se muestran antes de llamar a la
> función header(). Sucede el mismo problema cuando se utiliza un solo
> fichero PHP/HTML.

https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.header.php

Comment: A o, si comprendo, pero entonces como puedo direccionar si antes que esto tengo que hacer ciertas operaciones en mi Código?

Comment: Asegurándote de que no se produce ninguna salida. Tal vez si pones el código completo de tu archivo podamos ver dónde está el problema.